# How can I set a specific application to use a different port in IIS7?

Tags: iis, iis-7, port

I want to use a port other that port 80 for a specific application. (It's the speedtest.net mini app: http://www.speedtest.net/mini.php).

I want to use a port other that 80 for it, as we have a WAN optimisation tool on the network. As such, in order to get a "true" test (without the traffic having been cached or compressed) I need to add an exclusion rule in the WAN optimisation too for every host I want to run the test on. (If I stop optimising http traffic for all hosts it would defeat the point of the WAN optimisation tool!)

It would be much easier if I could run the test from some arbitrary port as I could then do a rule for all hosts on this port.

I can see how to edit the bindings for the Default Web Site, but not for a single application. (Or if I set another port up would this ripple to all applications, but wouldn't matter as they'd still be accessible on Port 80, too.)

End result is that I want to get to all my sites on port 80 except one:

```
http://myserver/speedtest:8765 (or some other port)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to go in Control Panel -> Windows Firewall -> Advace Settings -> and then Connecting Rules ( or something like that).

And it will load a list of all your program where you can change port and everything.